# Determine which pages textbox has text on multipage (SOLVED)

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to determine on which pages textbox has any value?
and getting the name of the non-empty textbox tab.
Setup:
On Page1 TextBox1, On Page2 TextBox2.
If TextBox2 has value init I need to get the name of the Page. 
Thanks in advance!

[image: Multipage]

What I've tried so far is to get values from specific textboxes.

```
a = ""
Dim r As Integer
For r = 5 To 12
    If step_0.Controls("TextBox" & r).Value <> "" Then
    a = a & " " & step_0.MultiPage1.Pages(r - 5).Caption
    End If
Next
```

Finally I managed and this worked for me.

Comment: This is no free coding service. What have you tried so far? Please include your code and explain where you got stuck or errors.

Comment: Code added Sir!

Comment: Note that if you found a solution yourself you should post it as an answer. After 1 day you should be able to mark your own anwser as official solution to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after thinking a little bit I found this solution.
This comes handy if you want to work with multipage captions combined with text boxes.
Code:

```
a = ""
Dim r As Integer
For r = 5 To 12
'according to count of textboxes should be 1 to whatever
    If UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & r).Value <> "" Then
    a = a & " " & UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(r - 5).Caption
'since the first page index is 0, subtract the integer. It only works if they arranged like this:
'page0-tbox1,page1-tbox2 page_n-tbox_n+1....
'a= creates a list with the captions of pages which has fulfilled textboxes.
    End If
Next
```